# ng-switch-when-separator not working in angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-switch

`ng-switch` is not working when i use **`ng-switch-when-separator`** .
when I select **settings** the switch is pointing to default div

```js
angular.module("myModule", [])
 .controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['settings', 'home', 'options', 'other'];
    $scope.opt = $scope.items[0];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <select ng-model="opt" ng-options="item for item in items">
        </select>
        <code>selection={{opt}}</code>
        <hr />
        <div class="animate-switch-container"
            ng-switch on="opt">
            <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="settings|options" ng-switch-when-separator="|">Settings Div</div>
            <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="home">Home Span</div>
            <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-default>default</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try this http://learnkode.com/Tryit/Example/Ng-Switch-1

Comment: [Their demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/jzYWNZiWzyLWkCnStVtW?p=preview) does the same thing... looks like a bug.  Click on the "Edit in Plunker" button.  It's weird, because it works on the documentation page.

Comment: Created a bug report https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15266

Comment: I looked at the `iframe` [source for the example](https://docs.angularjs.org/examples/example-ng-switch/index.html) on the documentation page - looks like it's fixed in 1.5.9 because it's using that version of angular.js.

Comment: Here's the proof using your code - http://plnkr.co/edit/tJSs8TDLUsuajr551jpw?p=preview  You can grab the 1.5.9 build [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/angular.min.js) and verify that it works for you.

Comment: Apparently the on is not necesary... look here: [AngularJS ng-switch Directive](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-switch.asp)

Answer (score 7):

This is an issue with the documentation page, but *not* a bug in Angular itself.
What happens:

- The docs by default show the API for the current *master* branch (also called snapshot)
- the embedded plnkrs also use the built angular files from the  master branch
- the automatically created plnkrs fall back to the latest stable version (in that case 1.5.8) which doesn't support the separator yet.

So you'll have to wait for 1.5.10 to use that feature.